# Mapping through a nested object in React

Tags: reactjs, loops, object, nested

I couldn't really find this anywhere else so here we go. I'm trying to map through a nested object and display the values but all I can get is the key displayed.

Object:

```
data = {
  objectOne: {
    name: "some name",
    otherValue: "something else"
  },
  someValue: "someValue",
  someOtherValue: "asdasd",
  objectTwo : {
    v1 : "v1",
    v2 : "v2",
    v3 : "v3",
  }
}
```

My function to loop through it: (I only want to display the content of objectOne)

```
Object.keys(data.objectOne).map(field => <div key={field}>{field}</div>
```

This returns `name` and `otherValue` but not the actual values.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` returns an array of the **keys** in the object, which explains why only the keys are being printed out. Try using `Object.values()` instead (ES2017):

```
Object.values(data.objectOne).map(value => <div key={value}>{value}</div>
```

Alternatively, you can stick with `Object.keys` and then use bracket notation to get the value for that key from the `data.objectOne` object:

```
Object.keys(data.objectOne).map(field => <div key={field}>{data.objectOne[field]}</div>
```